# Edit a new order email

Tags: email, tax, magento-1.9.2.1

I need to change the new order email. I need to edit this information:

- Subtotal (Excl. Tax)
- Subtotal (Incl. Tax)
- Shipment (Excl.Tax)
- Shipment (Incl.Tax)
- Total

  And this is in: design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/email/order/items.phtml

> Here I need to edit this: $this->getChildHtml('order_totals');

Because this function is where appears the table with all prices and tax. Where is this information? In a layout? or in a phtml?

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy this file to a local copy and modifiy it around line 90

`/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php`

There is something like this

```
/**
 * Initialize order totals array
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
 */
protected function _initTotals()
{
    $source = $this->getSource();

    $this->_totals = array();
    $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'code'  => 'subtotal',
        'value' => $source->getSubtotal(),
        'label' => $this->__('Subtotal')
    ));
```

Where you can edit all that

Comment: But.. If I modify this I'm sure that this will affect to others things, and I only need to edit the new order template.

Comment: this will edit the orders and how it is shown correct